# java, Interface class used as JPanel component

Tags: java, interface, jpanel

say i have an interface called IPanel.java which contains some empty methods, is it possible to use that interface as a component in a JPanel, like you can do with classes that extend JPanel?

Comment: It probably needs to extend Component.

Comment: an interface can only extend other interfaces, though. @SteveSmith

Comment: That's right, so you can't create an interface that can be used to add something to a container.  You'll need to change it to an abstract class maybe.